# Fizz OpenAPi generator for Gin is renaming types

Tags: go, openapi-generator, go-gin

I have created a simple API written in Gin. I used [Fizz](https://github.com/wI2L/fizz/) to generate an OpenApi 3 specification. Here is my POST endpoint:

```
// Sets user route group
func UserRoute(grp *fizz.RouterGroup) {

    // create new user
    grp.POST("", []fizz.OperationOption{
        fizz.Summary("Creates new user and sends verification mail."),
        ...
    }, tonic.Handler(handlers.CreateUser, 201))
}
```

And here is the handler method:

```
// Creates new user
func CreateUser(c *gin.Context, register *models.Register) error {
    ...

    return nil
}
```

The problem is that in the generated JSON specification the "**Register**" model shows as "**CreateUserInput**":

[image]

Is there any way to fix it or is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [implementation](https://github.com/wI2L/fizz/blob/fe54d355ba0184693a3dd34eeacfe1a03487dff1/openapi/generator.go#L439-L497), the schema name is generated by this statement: `name := strings.Title(op.ID) + "Input"` (see line `23` below):

```
 1  // setOperationParams adds the fields of the struct type t
 2  // to the given operation.
 3  func (g *Generator) setOperationParams(op *Operation, t, parent reflect.Type, allowBody bool, path string) error {
 4      if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
 5          return errors.New("input type is not a struct")
 6      }
 7      if err := g.buildParamsRecursive(op, t, parent, allowBody); err != nil {
 8          return err
 9      }
10      // Input fields that are neither path- nor query-bound
11      // have been extracted into the operation's RequestBody
12      // If the RequestBody is not nil, give it a name and
13      // move it to the openapi spec's components/schemas section
14      // Replace the RequestBody's schema with a reference
15      // to the named schema in components/schemas
16      if op.RequestBody != nil {
17          mt := tonic.MediaType()
18          if mt == "" {
19              mt = anyMediaType
20          }
21          sch := op.RequestBody.Content[mt].Schema
22          if sch != nil {
23              name := strings.Title(op.ID) + "Input"
24              g.api.Components.Schemas[name] = sch
25              op.RequestBody.Content[mt].Schema = &SchemaOrRef{Reference: &Reference{
26                  Ref: componentsSchemaPath + name,
27              }}
28          }
29      }
```

You can customize the operation ID with [fizz.ID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wI2L/fizz#ID), but there is no way to remove the `Input` suffix. You need to fork the repository and modify the implementation if you really want to generate the schema name differently.